# Symfony 2 - PostgreSQL - SQLSTATE[42809]: Wrong object type: 7 ERROR: column notation

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, debian

I'm learning symfony 2 currently. 
Before, I was using MySQL, but I wanted to try the power of Symfony 2 and doctrine. So I wanted to switch from MySQL to PostgreSQL. 
I have everything well installed... The database was created with the doctrine command, the dump was successful too... When I wanted to register a new user from the home page. I had this exception :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.username AS username1,
t0.username_canonical AS username_canonical2, t0.email AS email3, t0.email_canonical AS
email_canonical4, t0.enabled AS enabled5, t0.salt AS salt6, t0.password AS password7,
t0.last_login AS last_login8, t0.locked AS locked9, t0.expired AS expired10, t0.expires_at
AS expires_at11, t0.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token12, t0.password_requested_at 
AS password_requested_at13, t0.roles AS roles14, t0.credentials_expired AS
credentials_expired15, t0.credentials_expire_at AS credentials_expire_at16, t0.id AS id17, 
t0.nb_postes AS nb_postes18, t0.nb_following AS nb_following19, t0.nb_followers AS 
nb_followers20 FROM User t0 WHERE t0.username_canonical = ?' with params ["okay"]:

SQLSTATE[42809]: Wrong object type: 7 ERROR: column notation .username applied to type 
name, which is not a composite type
LINE 1: SELECT t0.username AS username1, t0.username_canonical AS us...
```

My queries worked very well with MySQL, but with PostgreSQL, I got this :/ .
I haven't found anything on the web about `ERROR: column notation` ... If one of you know how to resolve this please ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need escaping:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table("`user`")
 */
class User {
}
```

Those backticks will make Doctrine use `"user"` instead of `user` in the queries.

Comment: Exactly... Thanks for the tip dude !! 
But if I want User, with Uppercase for the first letter, I have to do exactly `"\`User\`"` .

Comment: Sure. I just prefer everything in lowercase in PostgreSQL because it's idiomatic. If my answer solved your problem, please don't forget to mark it as the right one.